# Sorting Factors

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

If I have a term that has the form

$f_1'(y).(ie^{i x})*f_2'(y).(2ie^{2 i x})$

Is there a way Mathematica can split the term and put each of its factors into an array or list?

What I am looking for is it to split the above term to

$ \{ f_1'(y).(ie^{i x}) , f_2'(y).(2ie^{2 i x}) \}$

Note: The periods between the $f$ and $e^{m i x}$ factors have to be there. This is to make sure the $e^{m i x}$ factors stay attached to their associated $f$ function. If they are not there, my previous code that supplies me with all my terms will multiply the $e^{m i x}$ factors together and I would end up with something like

$if_1'(y)f_2'(y)e^{3 i x}$

Now I cannot determine which $f$ function has the $e^{i x}$ and which had the $e^{2 i x}$

Thank you for any input.

Comment: `expr = f1'[y].(I*E^(I*x))*f2'[y].(2 I*E^(2 I*x)); 

List @@ expr`

Comment: I thank you very much @BobHanlon, this worked quite nicely. I had already used List@@ to split up a sum but I did not think it would work again with the factors.